# writeToFile and encoding (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, encoding

here is my code, i try to load a html file to an string variable then write it to a html file on computer again, but the problem is that when it export the file and i open the html file by browser it shows me the html content file unexpectedly!

```
  NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
        NSString *web=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];

   [web writeToFile:@"/saleh/index.html" atomically:YES encoding:***NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding*** error:&theError];
```

as i think  here is the problem encoding, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is problem of encoding, use `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://www.google.com"]];
NSString *web=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:theURL];
[web writeToFile:@"path/gp.html" atomically:YES encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```